# Image file is not showing even though the image url is assigned C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I tried a code to display a saved image from a folder to an asp:image control using image url. I used the following code

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="71px" Width="141px" />
```

and code in the cs page as

```
string theFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/Signature"), Filename);
Image1.ImageUrl = theFileName;
Image1.DataBind();
```

I can access the same image file from the address bar though the url for the image is correct. then what is the problem with this code?
when I inspect the webpage then it shows could not load the image. I am here attaching the scree shot for the same

[image]

Comment: When dealing with website images use only relative paths and do not navigate outside the root folder. So remove `Server.MapPath`.

Comment: Yes genius , that was the problem, @VDWWD thanks man

Answer (score 1):

`Server.MapPath` is used to determine the **physical path** (C:...\img...) of a file in a web project (~/img/...).

When displaying HTML, you should use **URL paths** `~/img/...` / `/img/...` / `img/...`. Thus don't use `Server.MapPath` on HTML tags.

Don't forget that users use a *web browser* to display pages and pictures. All contents they can access are only available through URLs. They don't have access to your hard drives directly. The web server *maps* the path in a URL to a resource. Resources can be dynamic (.aspx page) or static (a picture on hard drive).